how to find downloaded files, such as HTML files, in the Android Downloads folder?
This is the modern "scoped storage" way we are supposed to do this ridiculously simple thing:
public static void listFilesInDownloadsFolder(Context context) {
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = {
            MediaStore.Downloads._ID,
            MediaStore.Downloads.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Downloads.SIZE,
            MediaStore.Downloads.DATE_ADDED
    };

    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Downloads.DATE_ADDED + " DESC";
    String selection = MediaStore.Downloads.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"%.html"};

    try (Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder)) {
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                // Retrieve file details from the cursor
                long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Downloads._ID));
                String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Downloads.DISPLAY_NAME));
                long size = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Downloads.SIZE));
                long dateAdded = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Downloads.DATE_ADDED));

                // Print or process the file details
                System.out.println("File: " + displayName + ", Size: " + size + ", Date Added: " + dateAdded);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

variations without the filename wildcard don't work, and attempts with Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).listFiles() also do not work. The code walks to our two PNG files, but does not see the JPG file or the HTML file. (The goal is to give the user a list of HTML files to select WITHOUT subjecting them to the Downloads folder file picker.) Our folder looks like this, and the executable bits don't matter. The code also fails on a tablet without the executable bits, and I don't know where they came from...
gts9pwifi:/ $ ls -l ./storage/emulated/0/Download/                                                                                 
total 272
-rwxrwx--- 1 u0_a241 media_rw  16725 2024-04-14 08:31 FLIP0000\ Project\ Zone\ Report.html
-rwxrwx--- 1 u0_a241 media_rw 104503 2023-08-12 21:53 earthgrazer_ansmet_big.jpg
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a241 media_rw  68188 2024-04-14 10:27 screenshot_bitmap.png
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a241 media_rw  79125 2024-04-14 10:27 screenshot_filename_drawn.png.png


Pretty unclear what you are trying to achieve. Please write a clear story.

You do not have access to arbitrary files in Download, except for ones created by your app installation. "The goal is to give the user a list of HTML files to select WITHOUT subjecting them to the Downloads folder file picker" -- then you will need to download the content yourself from within your app. If you want to want the user to choose files downloaded via other apps, you have no choice but to use the Storage Access Framework (ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT / ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument).

the inner question remains why two files with ordinary (((LINUX))) groups and permissions should be invisible. I will probably solve my outer problem by registering a file extension and then let the user tap on the file to raise it in my app. I do not enjoy not being able to streamline this for our users, but at least they are technical and it's not a civilian app.
